# Ms Access Sending Email VBA - Office 365

Tags: vba, ms-access, automation, outlook, office-automation

Can anyone see what is going on with this VBA please? It allows us to display the email as .Display, but we're not able to automatically send with .Send. We have to keep .Send commented out.

```
Public Function SendEmails()

    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strBody As String
    Dim strEmail As String
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim AttendeeSubject As String
    Dim SchedClass As String
    Dim StartTime As Integer
    Dim strbody2 As String
    Dim strbody3 As String
    Dim SubjectHeader As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set db = CurrentDbSet rs = db.OpenRecordset("tempEmailSuccessfulRegistration", dbOpenDynaset)
    If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No emails will be sent becuase there are no records assigned from the list", vbInformation
    Else
        With rs
            While Not .EOF

                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
                AttendeeSubject = rs("SubjectHeader") & " Class Registration: " & rs("Attendee")
            
                strEmail = rs("emailaddress")
                  strSubject = AttendeeSubject
                  strBody = rs("Body1")
                  strbody2 = rs("Remember") & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                  strbody3 = rs("Remember1")
                                      
                  '------------------------------------
                  '------------------------------------
                  'EMAIL REFORMAT - FOR WEBINARS
                  '------------------------------------
                  '------------------------------------
                  Dim myPos As Integer
                  Dim strPasscode As String
                  Dim strMeeting As String
                  Dim strChecklist As String
                  
                
                  strChecklist = strChecklist & "</li></ol>"
                  
                  strBody = strBody & strChecklist
                  
                  'myPos = InStr(1, rs("ClassLocationRoom"), "P")
                  'strPasscode = Trim(Mid(rs("ClassLocationRoom"), myPos, 5000))
                  'strMeeting = Trim(Left(rs("ClassLocationRoom"), (myPos - 1)))
                
                  With OutMail
                    .To = strEmail
                    '.Subject = strSubject
                    .Subject = "TESTING - PLEASE DISREGARD"
                    
                    .HTMLBody = strBody & rs("Body2") & "<br>" & "<br>" & strbody2 & "<br>" & "<br>" & strbody3 & "<br>" & "<br>" & rs("Respectfully")
                    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Class:  " & rs("ClassName")
                    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "Location:  " & rs("ClassLocationat") & " "
                    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "Address:  " & rs("ClassLocationIn") & " "
                    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "Room:  " & rs("ClassLocationRoom") & " "
                    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "Instructor:  " & rs("ClassInstructor") & " "
                    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & strPasscode
                    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & strMeeting
                    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "On:  " & rs("classdate") & " at " & rs("starttime") & " " & rs("Classzone")
                    .Attachments.Add "N:\EVERYONE\MVL\Inspectors\InspectionManual\InspectionManual.pdf"
                    .Attachments.Add "N:\EVERYONE\MVL\Inspectors\Forms\TC 96-182.pdf"
                    '.Send
                    .Display
                
                  End With
                  On Error GoTo 0
                  rs.MoveNext
                  '------------------------------------
                  '-------------------------------------
            Wend
        End With
    End If

    On Error Resume 
    Next
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Function
```

We want to be able to automatically create and send emails with this code.

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: You might want to get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` line to see if an error is raised

Comment: Check the security settings in outlook or the antivirus. You should get a notification from outlook *"a program is trying to send an email on your behalf..."* with a countdown of about 10-15 seconds before being able to allow it.

Comment: I prefer to use CDO mail so I'm not dependent upon Outlook: https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=send-email-access-vba-cdo

Comment: Sorry about that. We get the error message:
"Outlook does not recognize one or more names."

Comment: Comment out 'On Error'. What happens when you do that? Also, aren't you supposed to use .Display before .Send?

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook object model may trigger security prompts or throw errors when using unsafe methods and properties when Outlook is automated from other applications. See [Protected Properties and Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/security/protected-properties-and-methods) for the list the properties and methods in the Outlook object model that are protected by the Object Model Guard. If untrusted code performs a get on these properties or uses these methods, under default conditions for how Outlook is set up, it will invoke a security warning/issue.

To avoid security prompts/issues when dealing with OOM:

- use a low-level API on which Outlook is based on and which doesn't trigger security prompts
- use a third-party component which allows to turn off/on security warnings, see [Outlook Security Manager](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) for more information
- install the latest version of any antivirus software
- use group policy to change default settings

Finally, you may find the following articles helpful:

- [Security Behavior of the Outlook Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/security/security-behavior-of-the-outlook-object-model)
- [Outlook Object Model Security Warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/security/outlook-object-model-security-warnings)

Answer (score 0):

I took the code and cut some stuff away, just to test it with less code.
After fixing two lines

```
Set db = CurrentDbSet rs = db.OpenRecordset("tempEmailSuccessfulRegistration", dbOpenDynaset)

On Error Resume 
Next
```

to:

```
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tempEmailSuccessfulRegistration", dbOpenDynaset)

On Error Resume Next
```

The program runs ok with no errors and send all emails with data from the table.

Here is the code I used:

```
Public Function SendEmails()    
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strBody As String
    Dim strEmail As String
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tempEmailSuccessfulRegistration", dbOpenDynaset)
    If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No emails will be sent becuase there are no records assigned from the list", vbInformation
    Else
        With rs
            While Not .EOF    
                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
                strEmail = rs("emailaddress")
                strBody = rs("Body1")
                '------------------------------------
                'EMAIL REFORMAT - FOR WEBINARS
                '------------------------------------
                With OutMail
                    .To = strEmail
                    .Subject = "TESTING - PLEASE DISREGARD"
                    .HTMLBody = strBody
                    .Send
                End With
                rs.MoveNext
            Wend
        End With
    End If    
    'On Error Resume Next
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Test the code and see if you can run it without errors!