# Sending email via Outlook 365

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am updating an old program. I noticed in the new build the email send doesn't work.

I searched for the reference. Is there a way of sending without the reference or where is the reference for Outlook 365 (local install)?

I searched for the location. I tried without references.

I lifted this code from examples on the web.

```vb
Public Function SendEmail2()
Dim varName As Variant
Dim varCC As Variant
Dim varSubject As Variant
Dim varBody As Variant
varName = "johnsullivanbnm@gmail.com"
varSubject = "Hello"
varBody = "Let's go"
DoCmd.SendObject , , , varName, varCC, , varSubject, varBody, True, False
End Function
```

Error message

> Runtime error 2046
> The command of action Send Object isn't available now

Comment: Microsoft Outlook ##.# Object Library?

Comment: object library is ticked in references. I wasn't sure if I needed something else

Comment: Public Function SendEmail2()

Dim varName As Variant
Dim varCC As Variant
Dim varSubject As Variant
Dim varBody As Variant

varName = "johnsullivanbnm@gmail.com"


varSubject = "Hello"


varBody = "Let's go"


DoCmd.SendObject , , , varName, varCC, , varSubject, varBody, True, False

End Function '

Comment: runtime error 2046

Comment: Instead of posting code in comments, please [edit] your question.

Comment: ^ and include the full error message, not just the number.

Comment: I can post my original code but it's a lot longer

Comment: As far as I can tell, references and code are the same. Can try Outlook automation instead of SendObject. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71619472/ms-access-sending-email-vba-office-365.

Comment: Did you post your actual email address so it can get scraped and then receive all sorts of scam emails? One reason Email will not send automatically is because EditMessage argument is set to True. However, that does not explain cause of error message. Maybe a clue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71619472/ms-access-sending-email-vba-office-365

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete sub to send e-mails from MS Access using Outlook.

```
Sub SendOutlookMail(mTo As String, Optional mCC As String, Optional mBCC As String, Optional mSubject As String, _
   Optional mBody As String, Optional mAttach As String, Optional mSender As String, Optional SendAsHTML As Boolean = False, _
   Optional DirectSend As Boolean = False, Optional TemplatePath As String = "")
' Important: if mSender is filled, it must be the technical name of the Outlook account
   
   Dim Attachment As Variant
   Dim i          As Long
   
   On Error Resume Next
   
   If oApp Is Nothing Then
      Set oApp = CreateObject("OUTLOOK.Application")
   End If
   If Len(TemplatePath) > 0 Then
      Set oMail = oApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(TemplatePath)
   Else
      Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
   End If
   With oMail
      .To = mTo
      .SUBJECT = mSubject
      .CC = mCC
      .BCC = mBCC
      If SendAsHTML Then
         .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & mBody
      Else
         .Body = .Body & mBody
      End If
      If Len(TemplatePath) > 0 Then
         ' In this sub I suggest that a template is always a html-template
         .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody
      End If
      .ReadReceiptRequested = False
      
      'Attachments
      Attachment = Split(mAttach, ',')
      For i = LBound(Attachment) To UBound(Attachment)
         .Attachments.Add Attachment(i)
      Next i
      
      If mSender <> "" Then
         .SentOnBehalfOfName = mSender ' Name of the Outlook account
      End If
      If DirectSend Then
         .Send
      Else
         .Display
      End If
   End With
End Sub
```